# BUILD FAILED when building apk with crosswalk

Tags: android, build, apk, crosswalk-runtime

I'm trying to build a web app with Crosswalk and I get an error while following the example tutorial from here : https://crosswalk-project.org/documentation/getting_started/run_on_android.html

Console :

```
>>python make_apk.py --package=org.crosswalkproject.example \ --manifest=xswag/manifest.json

Checking manifest file
Checking system requirements...ok
options.arch: x86

Starting application build (x86)
 * Checking keystore for signing
   No keystore provided for signing. Using xwalks keystore for debugging.
   Please use a valid keystore when distributing to the app market.
 * Updating project with xwalk_core_library
 * Checking for external extensions
 * Copying native libraries for x86
 * Building Android apk package with Crosswalk embedded (x86)

BUILD FAILED
C:\Users\Jules\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:601: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Users\Jules\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:653: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Users\Jules\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:698: null returned: 1

Total time: 4 seconds
Command "C:\ant-1.9.4\bin\ant.bat release -f C:\Users\Jules\AppData\Local\Temp\Example-2kvo67im\build.xml -Dkey.store=C:\Users\Jules\Desktop\crosswalk-11.40.277
.7\xwalk-debug.keystore -Dkey.alias=xwalkdebugkey -Dkey.store.password=xwalkdebug -Dkey.alias.password=xwalkdebug" exited with non-zero exit code 1
```

build.xml lines 683 to 701 :

```
<echo level="info">----------</echo>
<echo level="info">Handling Resources...</echo>
<aapt executable="${aapt}"
         command="package"
         verbose="${verbose}"
         manifest="${out.manifest.abs.file}"
         originalManifestPackage="${project.app.package}"
         androidjar="${project.target.android.jar}"
         rfolder="${gen.absolute.dir}"
         nonConstantId="${android.library}"
         libraryResFolderPathRefid="project.library.res.folder.path"
         libraryPackagesRefid="project.library.packages"
         libraryRFileRefid="project.library.bin.r.file.path"
         ignoreAssets="${aapt.ignore.assets}"
         binFolder="${out.absolute.dir}"
         proguardFile="${out.absolute.dir}/proguard.txt">
     <res path="${out.res.absolute.dir}" />
     <res path="${resource.absolute.dir}" />
</aapt>
```

Line 698 is **proguardFile="${out.absolute.dir}/proguard.txt">**

I have Python, ant, adb, Android JDK, Java and Oracle JDK installed and my Path variable is working.

Comment: I tried a new freshly installed windows with only the requirements for the crosswalk tutorial and i get the same error... -_-

Answer (score 1):

I was getting similar errors when building apk using apache-ant (1.9.7). 
I found that it needed java 8 version to convert it successfully (.class to .dex and then apk), initially I had java 7.

There needs to be some pre-requisite regarding versions of all the tools we use in this process i.e compliance of Android-NDK tools, Android-SDK tools, apache-ant an java (jdk/jre) versions in order to successfully get the apk. Since we do not get any relevant print/error message pointing to actual problem for such issues, we end up spending hard time to debug it. Thus make sure that you are all good with the versions of all tools in use.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, fixed it by installing lib32z1 lib32z1-dev

To see more verbose output try to use: 
python make_apk.py --package=org.crosswalkproject.example \ --manifest=xswag/manifest.json --verbose

Comment: I have not checked it in Windows.